# cordova build ios exited with exit code 65

Tags: xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

while building the ionic application with configuration, ionic cordova build ios --configuration=testing   , getting error  cordova build ios exited with exit code 65.

Xcode version : 15.2
Mac os : 14.1
Ionic version : 7.2.0
Cordova : 12.0

Please help me on this , struggling since 4 days.

I tried  un-install  and install cordova, and removed and added  cordova platform for IOS,
provisioning profile successfully configured.